# How to run python file by passing argument using bash script?

Tags: python, bash

I am very new to bash scripts.
I have a .txt file with string names separated by lines (have space between each string).

my.txt is:

```
my name 
my class
my room
```

When I run my python script using terminal. I need to pass arguments one by one.

```
python3 python_file.py -f 'my name'
python3 python_file.py -f 'my class'
python3 python_file.py -f 'my room'
```

It works fine. I want to use bash script for each string (my name, my class, and my room) individually and pass as an argument for a python script.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE; do
    #echo ${LINE}
    python3 pythonfile.py -f $LINE 
done < my.txt
```

It doesn't work as each string has a space between them (my  name), python assumes  as string and display error message

```
error: unrecognized arguments: name
```

When I ma trying to put quotes in bash script, it is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE; do
    echo \'${LINE}\'
    #python3 pythonfile.py -f $LINE 
done < my.txt 

output:
'my name
'my class
'my room
```

with same error message.

When I tried to put quotes inside .txt file, it doesn't even work then.

new: my.txt

```
'my name'
'my class'
'my room'
```

same error message:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: name
```

I do not want to do it with one python script by reading names one by one from my.txt file. I have some internal coding in python script that is not suitable for this. Hence I want to use bash.

Please guide.

Comment: It should have been `python3 pythonfile.py -f "$LINE"`

Comment: Have you already tried `python3 pythonfile.py -f '$LINE'` ? This should work.

Comment: @R.Joiny: That wouldn't work, as the variables in `bash` don't expand under single quotes. You need to double-quote it

Comment: @Inian Thank you so much. It worked :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is given by [Inian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5291015/inian). Can not accept that comment as answer so posting it here.

It should have been `python3 pythonfile.py -f "$LINE"`

Answer (score 1):

My Mac appears to give the expected output when I run this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE; do
    echo python3 pythonfile.py -f \'${LINE}\'
    #python3 pythonfile.py -f $LINE
done < my.txt
```

Noting that you don't see the final quote in your output, and neither do you strip anything from the input, I suspect that your data file was generated in a Windows environment and contains `<CR><LF>` terminations for each line.

So what your script is outputting (the shell strips the terminating line feed) for  each line of input is

```
'some name<CR>'<LF>
```

The effect of the carriage return is to overprint the first quote with the second one, making it "disappear". There's often a `dos2unix` or similar utility that will help you convert such data files.

Comment: I am new to bash as I mentioned. Yes the txt file was prepared in Windows. While passing the string (my name) it treats `'my'` as passing string for argument and treat `'name'` as second argument and shows error `unrecognized argument`.  `python3 pythonfile.py -f "$LINE"`solved the issue.

Comment: Yes, understanding the different quoting options is an essential part of the learning process.